# list Items of a category in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I am a beginner in drupal, I created categories using taxonomy, I added the terms,
)Cat1
-Accessories
-fourniture
)Cat2
-nature
-inside
the categories are shown in the menu-bar , but when i click on the Cat1 or Cat2
it gives me an empty node , I want it to show me the list of terms (Accessories, four...) !
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding terms to a vocabulary wouldn't create any association with nodes automatically.

[image]

In your content-type(s) you need to add a `Term reference` field for each vocabulary that needs to be associated with.

[image]

Then update existing nodes, for the term reference fields. That way you'd associate terms with nodes and when browse a term page, tagged nodes would be shown.

[image]